# How to create a session lock using JMeter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, jmeter, session-state, asp.net-session

I'm trying to recreate a session lock using JMeter with the setup below but i still can't recreate it. Can someone help me how to do it using JMeter?

Application Setup:

- SessionState Mode: SQLServer
- .Net Framework 4.5.2

JMeter Test Plan that I've tried:

1. First Test Plan

   - Thread Group - NumberOfThreads(users):30, Duration:5mins

     - HTTP Request

       - View Result
       - HTTP Cookie Manager - ASP.NET_SessionId:[Value]
2. Second Test Plan

   - 30 Thread Group - NumberOfThreads(users):1, Duration:5mins

     - HTTP Request

       - View Result

From what I understand, you can recreate a session lock if you run multiple request at the same time with only one session.

Comment: Please describe what are you testing, a web application based on NET or a SQL Server. What is your system under test (SUT)?

Comment: @MirkoEbert it is a web application based on ASP.Net. I'm trying to create a session lock from a GET request. i.e. www.samplewebsite.com/firstpage

Comment: If you try it manually e.g. with *curl*, did it work properly?